# Rails 4 Ajax not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am struggling to troubleshoot why this ajax call on a standard Destroy method won't work. From looking at my HTML source, I think it might be a problem with either how I'm creating divs using div_for OR it has something to do with my js. I'm at a loss for troubleshooting javascript.

My view:

```
<% @quizzes.each do |quiz| %>
  <%= div_for quiz do %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= link_to quiz.name, quiz_review_path(quiz.id) %> 
        </td>
        <% if quiz.finished? %>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Results", quiz_results_path(quiz) %>
        </td>
        <% elsif quiz.questions.first != nil %>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Take quiz", question_answer_path(question_id: quiz.questions.first.id) %> 
        </td>
        <% else %>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Broken, delete!", nil %>
        </td>
        <% end %>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Delete", quiz_path(quiz), method: 'delete', remote: true %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

The controller:

```
def destroy
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    @quiz.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to quizzes_path }
        format.js
    end
end
```

My views/quizzes/destroy.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= dom_id(@quiz) %>').fadeOut(); 
})
```

From looking at the Rails s logs, I can see that the delete request comes in and is processed by the js, so my best guess is it's either an issue with div_for and dom_id OR my js is bad (highly likely).

Comment: If you use firebug you could see what's append in the console. See also Rails UJS events to help you to debug https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: your "@quiz" is destroyed now take a backup before destroying "@backup = @quiz" then destroy it, and then in js.erb use "@backup"

Comment: cheers, with firebug I can see that there's something wonky going on with div_for - it creates the divs but doesn't seem to wrap the right content. Using divs around a table row is a nono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: trying to wrap  in a  with div_for creates invalid html. Removed the tables and now the ajax works fine.